# document.execCommand('insertHtml') not working twice when line is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When i use document.execCommand(insertHTML) twice (e.g. hitting enter twice to insert new paragraph) nothing will happen. So only one new line is created.

HTML:

```
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true"><p>Some text</p></div>
```

JS:

```
$('#editor').on('keyup keydown keypress',function(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 13){
    document.execCommand("insertHTML",false,"<p><br></p>");
    return false;
    }
});
```

So how can i create two new empty paragraphs when the user hits twice enter?

See also fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/auvnbz5o/ (hit enter twice and nothing will happen - only when u enter a character a new paragraph can be created)

Comment: Have you tried after commenting "return false" statement as it prevents execution of default event of editor?

Comment: You mean to leave out "return false"? So without return false there would be another problem -> When i press enter on a paragraph that has text inside two new paragraphs will be created at the same time ;)

Comment: return false prevents all subsequent events [keyup, keydown, keypress]! Pressing enter after removal "return false" statement, the written logic will be executed thrice in sequence keydown, keypress, keyup. Can you explain why you want to bind three events to execute same logic? Can't only Keydown event be sufficient?

Comment: Yes! You are right with that - but the problem still remains. I tried it with the jsfiddle here -> http://jsfiddle.net/auvnbz5o/1/

Comment: Do you have to use `document.execCommand()`? Or could you go for a jQuery-only solution?

Comment: jQuery only would be also fine. What would be your solution? ;)